# Click event on the keyboard: up, down, left, right

Tags: javascript, html, events, keyboard-events

I need an event that gives one click right, up, down or left. I want that when a condition is met (if) he give a click on the button I choose, below is an example in which should fit:

`if (gesture.left) {
The click event in the left direction button keypad 
} Else if (gesture.right) {
Click the event in the right direction button keypad 
}`

Do not want to detect which key was pressed, only one condition that after he click button that I want.

Comment: Do you want to dispatch a [*keyboard event*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-keyboardevents)? On which element?

Comment: I want to run direction buttons (up, down, left or right) so that a condition is accepted (if). 
Example: if (1 == 1) {Event selects the down key on the keyboard, thus making the page down}, took a crossbow example, but you know?

Comment: Ah.. is this the kind of questions made just to test if the reader is actually paying attention?... haha.. okay got it... So the answer is NO, no click events with the keyboard.

Comment: @AdrianSalazar—put focus on a button and press enter and you'll get a click event initiated by a key press.

Comment: @RobG you didn't read the part of up, left, down, right, right?

Answer (score 5):

arrow keys are only triggered by `onkeydown`, not `onkeypress`

keycodes are:

- left = 37
- up = 38
- right = 39
- down = 40

http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadhasankhan/qqqpf/2/

Comment: Have an example of how I do that, please. 

thank you

Comment: If you are trying to detect which key was pressed, try [MDN: event.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.keyCode) or [MDN: event.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.which) (there is also [MSDN: event.keyCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562920(v=vs.85).aspx) but MDN is likely more helpful).

Comment: I want to run direction buttons (up, down, left or right) so that a condition is accepted (if). 
Example: if (1 == 1) {Event selects the down key on the keyboard, thus making the page down}, took a crossbow example, but you know?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('html').keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
          }
          else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
          }
        else if(e.keyCode == 38) { // up
          }
        else if(e.keyCode == 40) { // down
          }
    });
});
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLtFk/89/)

You can also use `which` instead of `keyCode`, Like following:

```
$(function(){
        $('html').keydown(function(e){
            if(e.which== 37) { // left
              }
              else if(e.which == 39) { // right
              }
            else if(e.which == 38) { // up
              }
            else if(e.which == 40) { // down
              }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I want to run direction buttons (up, down, left or right) so that a condition is accepted (if). 
Example: if (1 == 1) {Event selects the down key on the keyboard, thus making the page down}, took a crossbow example, but you know?

Comment: Answering with a library that isn't tagged in the question is bad form. At least tell the OP what the library is (there are many that use *$* as a function name).

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
 <input id="target" type="text" value="Hello there">
</form>

<script>
  $("#target").keydown(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
     alert( "left pressed" );
     return false;
   }else  if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
     alert( "right key pressed" );
     return false;
   }else  if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
     alert( "Up key pressed" );
     return false;
   }else  if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
     alert( "Down key pressed" );
     return false;
    }
   });
</script>
```