# Click a specified event on the input in keyboard: up, down, left, right

Tags: javascript, html

I need an event that gives one click right, up, down or left. Below is the logic:

`if (gesture.left) {
 Click Event for left direction
} Else if (gesture.right) {
Click Event for right direction 
}`

I need to detect only one condition after the click button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arrow keys are only triggered by onkeydown, not onkeypress
keycodes are:

```
left = 37;
up = 38;
right = 39;
down = 40;
```

or you can look at this thread [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751582/click-event-on-the-keyboard-up-down-left-right/23751778#23751778)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(function(){
$('html').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
      }
      else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
      }
    else if(e.keyCode == 38) { // up
      }
    else if(e.keyCode == 40) { // down
      }
});
```

});